# Migrated from primefaces 5.1 to 8.0, selection is becoming null in datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable in a dialog

```
<p:dataTable id="effectiveList" var="item"
     value="#{bean.myEffectiveList}"
     emptyMessage="No records"
     rowKey="#{item}"  
     selection="#{bean.selectedArray}"..... />

    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
        listener="#{bean.showWarningMessage}"
        update=":form:tabView:messagePanel"/>
    
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width:30px;"/>
            <p:column headerText="Effective List" escape="false"/>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:30px;text-align:center"/>   

    <p:column id="col1">
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

myEffectiveList is List of strings. When my dialog loads for the first time, selectedArray is being set to selected for all check boxes. Say I have 3 rows in the datatable and all of them are selected. So selectedArray size = 3.

i unselect one of the row,

**Expected:** selectedArray=2 and only 2 rows should be selected and one should not be selected in the UI.

**Actual:** selectedArray=0 and 2 rows are selected and one is not selected in the UI(second part is correct)

I am not sure why selectedArray is becoming zero. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried a more recent PF.  This may have been fixed in 10, 11, or 12 since 8.0 release.

Comment: No, havent tried in above PF 8.0 version.